# Why is it unsafe to store login info in Cookies?

Tags: php, security, session, cookies, web

I've read that storing login information in cookies is a security risk since they can easily be edited by the user. My question is if all I store is the username and password in the cookies then why is it risky? If I just made a simple authentication script to make sure the password and the username match up before retrieving information from the database why would this be risky? The user editing the cookies would still need to know the correct username and password that match together to gain access.
I am planning on doing this so users can stay logged in after the session ends.

Comment: What if someone uses the website on a public computer?

Comment: You may need to use sessions instead, and use cookies just to get the session id (http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well if you store the username and password in the cookies, then they will be accessible to anyone with access to the computer.

This wouldn't be very secure.

Comment: Would it be advisable to simply md5 hash the password and store that as the cookie instead?

Comment: Imagine you store the user and md5(password). Now a malicious user accesses the computer and gets the user and the hashed password. He can easilly use these information to login anytime from any other computer (by simply modifying the cookie). So no it's not good either.

Comment: @EricSmith If you're firing the hash back and forth like that then the hash essentially becomes the password, and you don't actually need to know what the 'real' password is.

Comment: Alright yeah I see how that can be a problem now. So would the best option just be to store a unique ID and then access information from the database with the ID?

Comment: it doesn't matter what you store in the cookie, if you're authenticating with that any one with access to the cookie can just use it to authenticate

Answer (score 5):

No. Do not do this. This is pretty much the worst way to go about it.

A better solution is to:

1. Have the user log in.
2. Generate a random token, ie: `$token = md5( time() . rand() . $username );`
3. Store the token in the cookie, as well as in the database alongside the user's ID, and the IP address used for the login.
4. Start a session.

This way when the session expires you can still check the token in the cookie, compare it to what's stored in the database along with the IP address, and then process a non-interactive login for the user.

By doing it this way you're:

1. Not storing the user's credentials anywhere outside of the server.
2. Providing baseline protection against cookie hijacking.

You *should* also store a timestamp along with the token, and expire it after a reasonable period like 30 or 60 days so that users don't have themselves permanently logged into machines they may not want to be logged in on. As well, an option for a user to view and invalidate all of their login tokens so they can be responsible for their own account security.

re: @Gumbo's comment:

I think you're a bit fuzzy on what `rand()` does. Even if you know the user's name and the *exact second* that they logged in [via the server's clock] that still leaves you 2 billion possible values for `rand()`. [on my system] If you want to start just guessing MD5 hashes that's 2^128 possibilities, and it's all moot if you're not on the same IP address that's stored in the DB alongside the token.

The items were chosen off the top of my head for the following reasons:

1. `$username`: so the token should be unique per user.
2. `time()`: so the token is unique per second
3. `rand()`: so the token is reasonably random
4. `md5()`: because I felt like it. MD5's hexadecimal strings are easy to use in code, and in this context reversability is a moot point. We are only interested in making the guessing of tokens difficult.

Use `mt_rand()` and sha512 or bcrypt or I-don't-care-what, but the fact remains that it's not necessary in this context.

Comment: `time() . rand() . $username` is not that random.

Comment: If you intent to store tokens in db use Secure random only... You don't need any hash functions... If you wan't to be able to make decission based only on what users is presenting you, use atuhenticated encryption...

Comment: @Gumbo I think you're a bit fuzzy on what `rand()` does.